# is IOS 6 provide any way for getting MISSED CALL number and RECEIVED CALL numbers??

Tags: ios6, core-telephony

I want to know missed call number and received call number through my application.
Older ios versions(older than ios6.0) has no any method or frame work through which we can get missed call number and received call numbers list.

In older version of ios(older than ios6) i identified missed call by using this methods of application delegate.

- If the user accepts the call, applicationDidEnterBackground is called, and then when user switches back to your application applicationDidBecomeActive will be called.
- If the user rejects the call or the calling person ends the call before accept/reject, applicationDidBecomeActive will be called.

The second case indicates a missed call.

So i am asking that

1. Is newer ios6 provide any way for getting missed call numbers and received call numbers.???

Thanks.

Comment: [link](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/) This link has some useful information. But still i am looking for proper solution of my question. Please help me.